# spring batch failure in the end of the day

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

is there a solution that allows you to check on the jobrepository for a given job(JobInstance), the presence of a completed job during the day, if there is no completed status on the batch_job_execution table during the current day, so I must send a notification or an exit code like what we got nothing today.

i plan to implement the solution in a class that extends from JobExecutionListenerSupport, like this:

```
public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionNotificationListener.class);
private JobRegistry jobRegistry;
private JobRepository jobRepository;

public JobCompletionNotificationListener(JobRegistry jobRegistry, JobRepository jobRepository) {
    this.jobRegistry = jobRegistry;
    this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
}

@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    System.out.println("finishhhhh");
    //the logic if no job completed to day
    if(noJobCompletedToDay){
        Notify();
    }
    if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
        logger.info("!!! JOB FINISHED! -> example action execute after Job");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JobExplorer#getLastJobExecution`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html#getLastJobExecution-org.springframework.batch.core.JobInstance-) to get the last execution for your job instance and check if it's completed during the current day.

Depending on when you are going to do that check, you might also make sure there are no currently running jobs (`JobExplorer#findRunningJobExecutions` can help).

Comment: thank you for your response, can you provide me a example how i can pass the jobInstance to getLastJobExecution in the listener?

Comment: `JobExplorer#getLastJobExecution` takes a JobInstance as a parameter. Based on your description: `for a given job(JobInstance)`, I guess you have already the job instance so you can do something like: `JobExecution lastExecution = jobExplorer.getLastJobExecution(yourJobInstance);`

Comment: thank you, i will test that, and i have already watch one of your conference with michael minella :), and it's very usuful for me.

Comment: re, i have not the jobinstance in my listener but a jobExecution in my function afterJob in the listener of the job like in the code given in the description, can i get all the execution of this job during a day with this class ?

Comment: Using a job listener for this task is not appropriate IMO, because you need to run a job to invoke the listener. I think you need a separate app (scheduled at the end of day) that does the check and sends the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement monitoring in multiple ways.  Since version 4.2 Spring Batch provides support for metrics and monitoring based on Micrometer.  There is an example of spring [grafana sample][1], with prometheus and grafana from which you can rely to customize a custom board or launch alerts from these tools.

If you have several batch processes it may be the best option, in addition to these tools will help you to monitor services, applications etc.

Buily in metrics:

- Duration of job execution
- Currently active jobs
- Duration of step execution
- Duration of item reading
- Duration of item processing
- Duration of chunk writing

You can create your own custom metrics (eg. Execution failures).

Otherwise, you can implement the monitoring, for example, through another independent batch process, which executes and sends a notification / mail etc.  collecting for example the state of the process base, of the application or a filesystem shared between both processes.

You can also implement the check the way you describe it, there is an interesting thread where you can find described how to throw an exception in one step and process it in a next step that sends or not an alert as appropriate.